# Converting Simplified Math Notation to Latex/MathML

Tags: javascript, latex, converters, mathml, mathjax

I'm trying to implement a way for users to input simplified math notation, rather than the conventional LaTex notation. The result of the expression would then be rendered using MathJax. But I can't seem to find a "simplified math notation" or ad-hoc ASCII to latex/mathml notation convertor. Can anyone recommend a converter, if not a way to build the converter.

Comment: Do you have any specific syntax/notation in mind, or would accept any one?

Comment: I don't have any specific requirements on the sytax/notation; except that it has to be "simpler" than LaTex (ad-hoc ASCII for example). But there is no requirement on the syntax/notation.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a lightweight alternative to MathJax, at http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html

It includes an input syntax that's simpler than LaTeX, basically presentation MathML semantics with a Unicode text string syntax.  This syntax is then converted by javascript to MathML or simple HTML and CSS.  You can control this conversion from javascript.

If this looks like what you want, I could comment on the best way to embed it in your project.